# iterator_traits SFINAE friendliness

Tags: c++, type-traits

When reading the [excerpt](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) from cppreference

> If `Iterator` does not have the five member types `difference_type`, `value_type`, `pointer`, `reference`, and `iterator_category`, then this template has no members by any of those names (`std::iterator_traits` is SFINAE-friendly)

I automatically thought it meant each member type is defined when they are defined in the iterator itself. But lo and behold, it actually meant if *all five* are defined, then they are defined.

```
struct defined
{
    using difference_type = int;
    using value_type = int;
    using pointer = int*;
    using reference = int&;
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
};

struct undefined
{
    using value_type = int;
};

template<typename T>
using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type;

void foo()
{
    using std::experimental::is_detected_v;
    static_assert(is_detected_v<value_type, defined>);
    static_assert(!is_detected_v<value_type, undefined>);
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/g/wV8GRM)

Why is this? I would've thought it is friendlier if they were independent of each other. For example if an algorithm just needs to store the `value_type` somewhere and doesn't care about anything else.

```
template<typename It>
auto amazingfy(It first, It last)
{
    typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type v;
    for(; first != last; first++)
        v += *first;
    return v;
}
```

It will fail to compile on some iterator that only defined `value_type`, but funnily enough, succeed if it were instead `typename It::value_type v;`

Comment: There is no such thing as "some iterator that only defined `value_type`". If it only defined `value_type` it isn't an iterator.

Comment: What T.C. said. If it doesn't define all those things, it isn't an iterator, and so `iterator_traits` should not be used to enquire about it. If you want a "get its value_type" trait then write that, don't misuse `iterator_traits`. It really doesn't make sense for `std::iterator_traits<std::vector<int>>::value_type` to be valid.

Comment: As I understand it, the purpose of `iterator_traits` is both to facilitate the usage of iterator-related types _and_ to ensure that the given type is a proper iterator, and so the requirement of having all the type definitions is meant to avoid accidental construction of partially defined `iterator_traits` with types that just happen to have some member type called `difference_type`/`value_type`/etc...

Comment: Exactly. For example, `iterator_traits<std::atomic<int>>::difference_type` and `iterator_traits<std::atomic<int>>::value_type`, but `std::atomic<int>` is not an iterator.

Comment: @T.C. Iterators are defined by the operations it supports, aren't they? Pointers as iterators are by your definition anomalies, when they should be a special (not general) case.

Comment: @jdehesa I disagree. That is the exact opposite purpose of traits. Traits provide a uniform interface to type aliases, hence the existence of pointer specialization _and_ the allowance of user-defined specialization. The user-defined specialization is there _specifically_ because an iterator need not have all type aliases defined to be useful in a generic context through traits

Comment: @JonathanWakely The above, and note how `std::allocator_traits` does what you claim shouldn't happen. As long as `value_type` is defined, `std::allocator_traits` will have everything else defaulted to something if none is present

Comment: My point being, traits are supposed to be used to treat types equally, so why restrict it? I would've thought traits are supposed to solve the need to specialize for certain types (like the last example in post)

Comment: Don't use `allocator_traits` as an example of good anything, it exists to correct historical mistakes, and provide backward compatibility after large changes to the allocator requirements which would have made all existing allocator classes non-conforming.

Comment: `iterator_traits` works with pointers because there is a partial specialization. `iterator_traits` works with iterator classes because they provide the required typedefs. It *doesn't* work with arbitrary types because they are not iterators. Why on earth would you want `iterator_traits<atomic<int>>` to have any members? It's worth noting that the SFINAE-friendliness was added later, originally using it with types that aren't iterators was just undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Some insight can be gathered from corresponding proposal [N3844](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3844.pdf):

> With benefit of hindsight, it has from time to time been argued that
>   the SGI STL (and consequently C++98) erred in specifying
>   iterator_traits as a bundle of five type aliases, and that individual
>   iterator-related traits would have been a better design. Even if true,
>   this paper proposes no change to the basic bundled design, keeping to
>   an all-or-nothing principle.

So it looks like it was just to try to approach the current situation very cautiously and make the minimum change required to make the traits SFINAE-friendly. Selective inclusion of the member would lead to the half-defined traits, and apparently, this was considered a potentially far-reaching result.