# Why do *_iterators still require typedef something void after removing std::iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17

I use [ostreambuf_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostreambuf_iterator) as the case below:

Before c++17,

```
template< class CharT, class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT> >
class ostreambuf_iterator : public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag,
                                                 void, void, void, void>
```

requires us to determinate every parameter type of std::iterator, so, for `std::ostreambuf_iterator`, `void` is not so bad.

As we know, [std::iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator)  deprecated in c++17. So, iterators, should typedef their member types inside their own body,  for example:

```
Member type           Definition
---------------------------------------------
value_type                  void
difference_type          void
pointer                        void
reference                     void
iterator_category       std::output_iterator_tag
```

Question:

Why should these void types still be typedefed? IOW, I think

```
Member type           Definition
---------------------------------------------
iterator_category       std::output_iterator_tag
```

is enough. After all, the motivations for deprecating `std::iterator` is just to simplify the standard(library). So there should be some reasons that I cannot figure out.

After googling, I found [a question about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619551/output-iterators-value-type)  on stack overflow, and the answer said:

> Defining it as a void, on the other hand, can prevent errors like:
>
> ```
> typename Iter::value_type v = *it; //useless with an output iterator if it compiled
> ```

But I think if we don't typedef `value_type`, such errors can also be prevented.

Comment: I would say it is related to [std::iterator_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) (which is SFINAE friendly since C++17)

Comment: `T*` is a [*ContiguousIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousIterator), but does not have a member `value_type`. You should use `typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type` not `typename Iter::value_type` when you want to handle **all iterators**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because ISO C++17 `std::iteartor_traits` needs all the 5 of these member types in general, even if it is already SFINAE-friendly since C++17. If there are insufficient nested types, the instance of `std::iterator_traits` will have no members desired. Currently, this is not changed [in the current draft](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/iterator.traits#2).

See also [iterator_traits SFINAE friendliness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260285/iterator-traits-sfinae-friendliness) for rationale of the original proposal.